# Powershell - error checking for find and replace (ForEach-Object)

Tags: powershell, error-handling, pipeline, error-checking

I need to add error checking on the ForEach-Object part.

Currently, this code works to replace a value in a file.  However, if it can't find the value, it doesn't seem to generate any error.  I have done a try and catch but it just isn't working.  I've searched for hours and tried all kinds of stuff ... any help?

I can do the command two different ways, not sure what is better or easier to add error checking on...

```
(Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $replace, $with } | Set-Content $file
```

-OR-

```
ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $file) -replace $replace, $with } | Set-Content $file
```

Thank you.

Comment: How about doing a check to see if the last command run was successful or not using `$?`

Answer (score 0):

finding nothing to replace is not an error, it just returns the original back. so check for it in an if statement, like:

```
foreach { $rep=$_ -replace $replace,$width; if ($_ -eq $rep) {...} }
```

Comment: That also did not work for me for some reason.  I ended up just using select-string boolean in some if statements.  Looks messy.. but it works.
    if ((Select-String $replace $file -Quiet) -eq $true)

Comment: the following displays _found_ and _not found_ for me. you can try and see what you're doing wrong: `"a:a","bbb"|foreach {$rep=$_ -replace ':','#'; if ($_ -eq $rep) {"not found"} else {"found"}}`